# Get data from inside of an anchor tag in Python

Tags: python

I want to extract '26' from the anchor tag below. How should I get it?

```
<li>    
<a href="https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/2569/7/26?per_page=100" data-ci-pagination-page="26">Last</a>
</li>
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=parse+html+with+python

Comment: check out the BeautifulSoup package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to use [beautiful soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). For instance:

```
html_data = """<li>    
    <a href="https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/2569/7/26?per_page=100" data-ci-pagination-page="26">Last</a>
</li>
"""
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
soup.find('a').get('data-ci-pagination-page')

# 26
```